# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

So im trying out pytesseract and then i get and error.

So this is my code `from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tsrt

tsrt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Users\DIPU\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR'

## Simple image to string

image_path = 'Images/test.png'  # Update this with the correct file path if necessary
print(tsrt.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path)))
`

And i got this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okcNg.png)

Comment: Use `\\U` instead of `\U`

Comment: Use raw string for path or escape path correctly. At the end of day it will not work as you did not set up variable according documentation (https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract)

Comment: Please format the code. Place code between triple backticks ```some code ```